# .htaccess redirect replacing & sign with the search

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, replace

```
RedirectMatch 301 /out/link http://www.link.com/?getparam1=something&getparam2=somethingelse&getparam3=more
```

When you click on mysite.com/out/link it goes to:

```
http://www.link.com/?getparam1=something/out/linkgetparam2=somethingelse/out/linkgetparam3=more
```

Basically its replacing the & sign, for the http 'get' params, with the /out/link part

Comment: using `\&` where appropriate worked.  It was reading it as regex I think... Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 5 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly try with the B flag

> Escape non-alphanumeric characters before applying the transformation.

So you would have
    RedirectMatch 301 /out/link http://www.link.com/?getparam1=something&getparam2=somethingelse&getparam3=more [B]

Comment: There is no spoon … erm, sorry, **flag** for the RedirectMatch, just
`Redirect [status] URL-path URL` (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you absolutely want to avoid escaping all the ampersands `&`: 
If you write a `RewriteRule` instead of a `RedirectMatch` directive, the ampersand in the query will not be replaced by the entire match ($0).

So, the two next lines appear same to the user: (note the second line has an unescaped `&`)

```
RedirectMatch ^/product-id/(.*) http://www.example.com/?foo=bar\&product_id=$1 
RewriteRule   ^/product-id/(.*) http://www.example.com/?foo=bar&product_id=$1 [R=301]
```

If you want the right-side URI visible to the user, use the [R] flag as indicated. If you ommit the flag, the user will be shown the left-hand URI (typically the more elaborate one, so maybe you dont need the flag).

It will act the same way, but it is likely to be less performant (google RedirectMatch vs. RewriteRule) for more on performance. Please keep in mind that all these Regex-Rules are evaluated for every single request on your webserver.