# Use .htaccess to redirect with any appended text transferred to new redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

I'm a little stuck. I have the following redirect in .htaccess

```
Redirect http://www.domain1.com http://www.domain2.com/subdomain=
```

Although I want that if someone types www.domain1.com/**12345**, it will automatically append the 12345 to the redirect URL on redirect so it will go to www.domain2.com/subdomain=**12345**.

i.e. whatever they append to the original, will be appended to the new redirect (without a / before it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect`. See [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)

> Resource Moved to Another Server
>
> ```
> #With RedirectMatch RedirectMatch "^/docs/(.*)" "http://new.example.com/docs/$1"
> ```

In your case:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/subdomain=$2
```

Comment: Thanks! Just tried this, but it seems to redirect to the homepage instead i.e. just www.domain2.com, any thoughts?

Comment: `it seems to redirect to the homepage instead`. Can you explain this phrase. I understood: you go to `www.domain1.com/12345` and it redirects to `www.domain2.com` instead of `http://www.domain2.com/subdomain=$2`. Is this your current problem with suggested solution? Or I misunderstood you?

Comment: Managed to fix it! There was an & symbol in the redirect link which for some reason automatically got replaced?! Therefore, the site cannot find the page and redirects to homepage. I added a backslash before the & sign and it worked.. I may not have explained it properly, but it was basically this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905048/htaccess-redirect-replacing-sign-with-the-search - Thanks though @alexander.polomodov, much appreciated!